# 'function' object has no attribute 'inertia_'

Tags: python

here is the part of the code where the error occurs:

```
k = 2

K = range(1, len(dist) +1)

models = [KMeans(n_clusters = k, random_state=42).fit]
dist = [model.inertia_ for model in models]

plt.plot(K, dist, marker='+')
plt.show
```

I get this payment message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-cb9780180c3e> in <module>()
      1 models = [KMeans(n_clusters = k, random_state=42).fit]
----> 2 dist = [model.inertia_ for model in models]
      3 
      4 plt.plot(K, dist, marker='+')
      5 plt.show

<ipython-input-44-cb9780180c3e> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 models = [KMeans(n_clusters = k, random_state=42).fit]
----> 2 dist = [model.inertia_ for model in models]
      3 
      4 plt.plot(K, dist, marker='+')
      5 plt.show

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'inertia_'
```

I also don't understand what exactly is considered a "function" object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *looks* like you're using a function rather than the result of a function. You may want to try calling the function to get the results:

```py
models = [KMeans(n_clusters = k, random_state=42).fit()]
```

Note the `()` at then end. Without that, you're simply storing the function itself into the list, *not* calling the function and storing its result.

However, keep in mind you may find you need to pass in some parameters (`K` perhaps?) to get it to do what you expect.

Comment: I changed the name "models" to "m" and changed the variable K as shown in the example (K = range(1, 11)) now I get an error:

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)